# Front end appropriate loader error using react

Tags: reactjs, npm, core-ui

I am trying to build a web app solution that uses [react](https://reactjs.org/) and [coreUI](https://coreui.io/?affChecked=1) as front end components.

The dev environment has been created from scratch with a clean install of windows together with various dev tools and IDE's.

The code was pulled and a `npm install` was run.

Upon running the solution I get the following error:

[image]

The error is front-end in nature as the backend runs but the browser cannot load the webpage.

The code base to which I have been onboarded to is too large and complex to try to comment-out/unplug certain components one by one.

I would appreciate any guidance or tips on how to resolve this issue. Is it an npm build issue? Dependency issue?

I may appropriately edit the answer if any further information is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio was not run in administrator mode. Running it in administrator mode solved the issue.